# Phonegap Android configurations failed:could not build android template project of phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I created a project of phonegap and complied for ios, it worked well. But for Android,when I used "cordova platform add android"or "cordova -d platform add android" commands, I got this error: "The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your path."

When I used "phonegap build android" to built project it prompted for username and password of github.com or build.phonegap.com. I made accounts of both. But when I entered username and password,it said its invalid. How should I build phonegap android app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to install the Latest version of Android i.e **4.3**

Go to **SDK Manager** and install the **latest SDK Platform**.

And try run the command again.

```
cordova platform add android
```

[image]

Hope this will help you.